# What microcontroller cores are used in cheap USB3.x card readers?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

As a home project I am looking at making myself a microSD/SD card reader. I would like to use a development kit and evaluation board such as ST Nucleo series. But ST don't seem to have any USB3.x capable cores, and looking at Cypress cores, they are very expensive.

If Cypress is the way to go, ok, but I was wondering what commodity controllers are available. I would like to get U3 speeds from my project.

Comment: Typically these use simple ASICs that map SD commands to USB MSC commands and copy data appropriately. I see lots on digikey, but can't comment on how cheap you think they are. Doing this on a microcontroller is possible (see open source projects like Rockbox which have SD and MSC drivers), but a lot of work since you need a whole USB stack.

Comment: @user1850479, these ASICs also need to determine SD card capabilities and file structure, not just "simple" map USB class requests into SD selrial commands (which is a no simple matter BTW). So most USB-SD adapters use some MCU to do the job.

Comment: @Ale..chenski MSC and SD have no concept of files or anything like that, so a simple SD to MSC adapter doesn't need to know anything about the file structure on the card.  The ones I've used are trivial, they just translate between MSC commands and SD commands.

Comment: @user1850479, and how do you think the bridge is reporting correct block structure and card capacity to host controller, how do they select proper card speed/voltage? Of course  if you plan to use the entry-level 1-wire mode, than maybe you can do this, but it would not fit the USB 3 speeds...

Comment: @Ale..chenski Maybe I don't understand what you meant by "file structure" but it sounded like you were saying the SD card controller has to access the file system on the card.  What did you mean by that?

Comment: @user1850479, sorry wrong term. I meant that the USB bridge must identify LBA structure of the particular plugged-in SD and report this via sense requests. There could be different mappings at block, page, and sub-page levels, which might need proper translation. In my opinion, the implementation of USB3 card reader is quite a challenge for a "home project".

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does have ASICs that do USB3-to-SD, but if you're talking "cheap", then you're probably looking at one of the several chinese-market ASICs that you'll have a hard time buying in small quantities.

Other than that, asking for product recommendations is off-topic, and you already seem to know which company's portfolio to scan for products, so asking here has little benefit.

Comment: I've looked at ST and Cypress. Granted, I can't use one of those chinese ASICs for the reasons you give. I've looked at other companies, and not found anything than better Cypress Semis selection, and nothing close to STs range. I'm not asking for a product recomendation, so much as trying to get a feel for what companies to look at. Seemed quickest to ask here. If this is the wrong forum, then where should I ask?

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think that card readers use any MCU cores at all? That it not true. They are build around some sort of ASIC, i.e. specific IC which provides USB-Mass Storage bridge only. They don't have to process or work with the data on storage cards so they don't need an MCU core at all. Mass producing such ICs are generally cheaper on high volumes than a more complicated MCU with complete USB 3.0 IP core included.

Comment: Well, technically, these controller ASICs implement a complex state machine that runs instructions from memory, has its memory integrated and communication peripherals on the same chip: that fulfills the definition of a microcontroller. Practically, it's not a microcontroller.

Comment: @mmmm doesn't MCU definition implies it should be programmable by the user in any way? Even if those has a mask-ROM, you can't order them with your custom code.

Comment: Usually, these things have a bit of user memory, not only to store things like the USB pid and vid, but also to allow users to write a bit of code to initialize gpios

Comment: These ASICs also need to determine SD card capabilities and file/block structure, not just a "simple" map USB class requests into SD serial commands (which is a no simple matter BTW). And there are hundreds of different varieties SD/MMC cards, running at different modes. Plus connect-disconnect and error recovery. So most USB-SD adapters do use some embedded general-purpose MCU to do the job, running thousands lines of C++ code.

Comment: @Ale..chenski file structure?! Seriously? USB-SD adapter can't even know which filesystem will be used by the host. While it might have internal MCU core, it's not an end-user programmable usually so it's not a general purpose MCU at all anyways.